# Is $\frac{A}{2}$ defined, when $A$ is a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $A$ is a matrix, can I write something like $A = \frac{A}{2} + \frac{A}{2}$ ? Because I remember that it's not allowed to divide matrices

Comment: It makes sense because $\frac{1}{2}$ is a real not a matrix

Comment: It's fine since $A=(a_{ij})_{ij}$ and $\frac{A}{2}=\left(\frac{a_{ij}}{2}\right)_{ij}$

Comment: You are not allowed to divide *by* matrices.  However, you can *divide* a matrix by a *scalar* (a number).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, dividing matrices is problematic, since the multiplication is neither commutative nor do all matrices have multiplicative inverses. However, dividing by a non-zero scalar $\lambda$ can be defined as $\frac{A}{\lambda} = \frac{1}{\lambda} A$, where now scalar multiplication is defined by multiplying each of the entries of $A$ with $\frac{1}{\lambda}$, effectively dividing all entries of $A$ by $\lambda$.

Answer (score 3):

Here, $\frac{A}{2}$ means $\frac{1}{2}A$ which makes sense as it is simply multiplying a matrix by a scalar.